# Sorting list from greatest to least

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, compare

what I am trying to do is sort the values from a list from greatest to least. i am trying to use Collections.sort(mylist) but i am not sure of what comparator to use to sort them from greatest to least. any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What contents are inside the list? Numbers?

Comment: yes it is a list of integers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it this way too

```
    Collections.sort(myList);
    Collections.reverse(myList);
```

***Edit:***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myList.add(5);
        myList.add(1);
        myList.add(3);
        myList.add(2);
        myList.add(9);
        myList.add(15);

        Collections.sort(myList);
        Collections.reverse(myList);
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ez4nick If your List contain integers this will work. what is the issue?

Comment: @ez4nick check this my Edit part

Comment: i figured it out, i didnt do reverse() i only did sort(), it works exactly as i wanted now thanks

Answer (score 3):

You likely need a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your your contained objects, or that your objects implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) will then do what you want.

Note also you'll likely result in an ascending result, and you can reverse the result using [Collections.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29), instead of creating a new comparator.

Npote also the referenced methods sort *in place* and will affect your original list. You may wish to create a new sorted list (in which case duplicate the list and *then* sort it)

(I see now you're using Integers, and the above applies wrt. Comparable)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted standard for a comparator for an increasing sort is `o1.intValue()-o2.intValue()`

We'll simply reverse this:

```
Comparator ourComparator=new Comparator<Integer>(){
public int compare(Integer o1, Integero2) {
    return o2.intValue()-o1.intValue();
}
```

You can then do as follows:

```
Collections.sort(ourCollection, ourComparator);
```

The reverse operation would only apply if your list was already sorted ascending going in, which cannot be guaranteed as you didn't specify your types.

Comment: I tried this and got the error: Class 'Anonymous class derived from Comparator' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'compare(T, T)' in 'Comparator'

Comment: @ez4nick I've got to apologize, I missed that comment from months ago and have just fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to sort by id for example:

```
    public static class SceneComparator implements Comparator<Scene> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Chair sc, Chair scc) {

        return (sc.getId() > scc.getId()) ? -1
                : (sc.getId() < scc.getId()) ? 1 : 0;
    }

}
```

---

```
    List<Scene> scenes = myClass.getScenes();
    Collections.sort(scenes, new ScenesComparator());
```

Hope you find it usefull

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

this is short and sweet:

```
Integer[] numArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6};

List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numArray));

Collections.sort(numList , Collections.reverseOrder());
```

**OUTPUT:**

[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

Answer (score 0):

This is another clean solution.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1, 6, 3, 8, 5, 9, 2, 7, 4);
        lst.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());

        System.out.println(lst);
    }
}
```

Output

```
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```